# md-require-match and autofill md-chips

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, md-chip

issue is 
To restrict md-chips to fill only by autocomplete options no other chip should allowed.

any suggestions?

ty in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `md-require-match` to `true` on the Md-chips element.

[From the Ng Material Docs:](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips)

> md-require-match  boolean  If true, and the chips template contains an
>   autocomplete, only allow selection of pre-defined chips (i.e. you
>   cannot add new ones).

Also see the [Custom Inputs Demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips) 
 from Ng Material Docs [2](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips)